# Using FullPage.js to create 2 scrolls in opposite direction on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, fullpage.js

I need some help as my JavaScript is not as strong as I like.

I'm working on a projected using https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js which I can get to work very well.

However, I need to have 1 half of the screen scrolling downwards and the other half scrolling upwards (at the same time).

As the user scrolls down the right hand side will scroll from bottom to top (default actions) and the left will scroll from top to bottom with a matching number of 's on each side.

There are menu items, so when one is clicked the left will scroll up and the right will scroll down to a pre-determined 2 sections.

Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Thanks, Jack.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I was trying to avoid using another Js library and working with parallax. But I think I might have to dive into Skrollr...

Comment: Ah Skrollr, good choice!